# make a condition based on a time (not hours)

Tags: excel

I would like to make a condition to use IF formula when the cell A1 with a date in this format YYYY-MM-DD 20:30 has the time higher than 18:30 (date is not important and should not be taken in consideration).

For example 2000-01-22 20:30  follows under this condition and 2015-02-22 15:30 doesnt.

Any tip?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rely on the underlying decimal representation of datetimes in Excel.  Just check if the decimal part of your date is greater than [your time]/24.0 :

```
=if(MOD(A1,1) > 18.5/24, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

How's this (if your data is in cell A1, place this in B1):

`=IF(AND(HOUR(RIGHT(A1,5))>=18,MINUTE(RIGHT(A1,5))>=30),"After 6:30 PM","Before")`

Note: This includes 18h30. To exclude it, just change the equation to simply `>`.